# Runtime error in accessing vector from reverse order C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have tried to access values stored in a vector in reverse order. The following code shows no error:

```
for (long long int i = 0; i < end.size(); i++)
    cout << end[end.size() - 1 - i] << "\n";
```

But the following code shows runtime error:

```
for(long long int i = end.size()-1;i>=0;i--) cout<<end[i]<<"\n";
```

Is there any difference between the two methods?

Comment: Unrelated, but containers in C++ has `rbegin` and `rend` (reverse iterators).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Can you prepare a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: *Is there any difference between the two methods?* -- Try your second method on an empty vector.

Comment: Don't call your vector `end`, that just confuses things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any difference between the two methods?

`end.size()` returns `std::size_t` which is an unsigned type. Given an empty vector, you subtract 1 from unsigned zero. The result is a very large unsigned number due to modular arithmetic that unsigned numbers use.

Here, the behaviour depends on the version of the language, as well as the implementation. If `long long` can represent the large unsigned value, then you overflow the array with this large index (any index being outside the bounds of an empty vector) and behaviour will be undefined. This would happen on 32 bit systems where `std::size_t` is presumably 32 bits and long long 64 bits.

If the value is unrepresentable by `long long`, then prior to C++20, the resulting value will be implementation defined. If that value is negative, then you have desired behaviour, other wise undefined behaviour. After C++20, the result would be congruent with a representable value modulo the number of representable values. If bit width of `long long` matches with `std::size_t`, then the result would be -1 and behaviour would be as desired.

In conclusion: Latter approach is broken on some implementations. The first one doesn't have this problem.

Comment: why "theoretically"? Its just broken, no?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 On systems with 2's complement representation and `long long` of same size as `std::size_t`, it would work in practice. Such systems are fairly ubiquitous. The problem is essentially with portability to systems that don't match that description.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I removed "theoretically" since it occurred to me that the problem exists on all 32 bit or smaller systems.

Answer (score -2):

The proper way to do it is:

```
for(auto i=end.size(); i-- ;) cout << end[i] << "\n" ;
```

Comment: not it is not. The proper way is to use reverse iterators. Anyhow you are not answering the quesiton

Comment: That's not the "proper" recommended version; it's not even equivalent (it doesn't print the first value).